# Dynamically add partition in table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with date column and other data. I want to create 3 partitions:

1. Data <= Previous year
2. Data = current year and month less than 2 months from current month
3. Data = previous month and current month

How do I get this, without having to manually recreate partitions each time a new month begins?